# Implemented custom data storage, bot still calls state.botframework.com

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

**Summary:**

We implemented TableBotDataStore in our C# Bot, but somehow the bot is still making calls to the deprecated State API.

**Context:**

In Application Insights I can see that our bot is making and a lot of calls to state.botframework.com. I also noticed that our production environment get's 200 responses on those requests, but our new Web App Bot is getting a 405 (Method Not Allowed) on all those request.

When we started developing the bot (May, 2018) we implemented the Azure Table Storage right away. So I was quite surprised to find that our bot is still calling state.botframework.com.

[This blogpost by MS](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/04/02/reminder-the-bot-framework-state-service-has-been-retired-what-you-need-to-know/) states:

> Read options will continue to be available through July 31st 2018

My assumption is that MS still allows requests to the State API for bots that were registered before a certain date.

**What I tried:**

I have already followed Microsoft's guide on how to [Manage custom state data with Azure Table Storage for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). I also read the related question [Migrated bot state provider but calls to state.botframework.com are still being made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944060/migrated-bot-state-provider-but-calls-to-state-botframework-com-are-still-being) but it doesn't help me.

**My code:**

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(
builder =>
{
    builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

    var store = new 
    TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureWebJobsStorage"]); 

    builder.Register(c => store)
        .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
        .AsSelf()
        .SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c => new CachingBotDataStore(store,
    CachingBotDataStoreConsistencyPolicy
        .ETagBasedConsistency))
        .As<IBotDataStore<BotData>>()
        .AsSelf()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    });

GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

**What I expect:**

With this configuration, I expect that our bot only uses the TableBotDataStore and doesn't make any calls to the deprecated State API.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot or code block of the full error?

Comment: Is your code calling .GetStateClient() anywhere?  This will only retrieve the default state client, and not your registered IBotDataStore<BotData>

Comment: @EricDahlvang Nope.. I have searched for it but the only place I can find "GetStateClient" is inside the package Microsoft.Bot.Connector. But my code never calls it..

Comment: @JJ_Wailes I updated my question because we found out that the deployment issues were caused by something else. 
So it's no longer causing errors, it's just that our bot calls the State API. Sometimes these calls take up to 20 seconds, which delays our bot..

Comment: Do you modify the autofac container in code that executes after the above registration?  (maybe something is overwriting the entire autofac container, so the above registration is no longer in use)  Can you share the project somewhere?  There is not enough to go on here.

Comment: @EricDahlvang Apologies for my late reply!
We do in fact override `Autofac.Module`. We do this to be able to register `PostUnhandledExceptionToUserOverrideTask ` (a custom implementation of `IPostToBot`). It allows us to handle exceptions with our own custom message. 

Please check out [our code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/uQ89EpZJ).

Comment: How are you registering DefaultExceptionMessageOverrideModule ?  I'm not seeing it in the code above.

Comment: I my Application_Start(). I should've posted the full Application_Start earlier. But here it is: https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/irySTs1B

Comment: Nothing there indicates a possible issue. :(  You could debug with the emulator, step through the code and watch the emulator log for calls to state.setConversationData, state.getConversationData, etc.

Comment: I tried the code in your pastebin against a v3.20.1 bot and it only used the TableBotDataStore.

Comment: Exactly which version of BotBuilder V3 sdk are you using?